# Sealed Bacon Left In an Ice box

Tags: bacon

Is it ok to eat sealed pack bacon after I accidentally forgot, left it in an ice box without ice for 8 hours? Its frozen when I left it. And after 8 hours its still cold.

Answer (score 3):

The question though is *how cold*? And you've missed the chance to measure that. If it felt cold then the chances of it having spent significant amounts of time above a safe temperature are low (given your description).

In a commercial situation you'd have to discard it (in any set of rules I've come across), but at home you can make a judgement call which may not be the same.